# One Model without nested Form Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have only one user model, I want to give add more option on the form.
There are many example have nested form but in my case no need to nested because I have only one user model.
I want to save bulk of users using add more form

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<%= form_tag users_path do %>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <%= fields_for 'users[]', user do |u| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= u.label :name %><br>
        <%= u.text_field :name %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag %>
  </div>
<% end %>

def create
  params[:users].each do |user|
    # create
  end
end
```

Comment: I want to add multiple user dynamic by clicking on the add more user link or remove user link and after that click on save button then save all the users form at a time

<%= f.link_to_add "Add a user", :users %>

Comment: nested_forms cannot do what you want. You can do it manually like shown above.